# Collation in Snowflake

Tags: sql, ssis, collation, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

we created a snowflake table as shown and loaded data into into from flat file using copy into command

```sql
create or replace table temp.T_ERROR
(
    ID NUMBER(38,0) Primary Key,
    ERROR varchar(4) collate 'en-rtrim' NOT NULL,
)
```

so we saw rtrimmed values in ERROR then we tried to transfer these results into another snowflake table with no collate option set on this table

```sql
create or replace table DATA.T_ERROR_1
(
    ID NUMBER(38,0) Primary Key,
    ERROR varchar(4) NOT NULL,
)
```

**ISSUE**:
the `DATA.T_ERROR_1` table is not getting the trimmed values from temp table instead its getting un-trimmed values which are in the original flat file

is there any other ways i can do this transfer which doesnt involve me writing rtrim ltrim or trim or every column

Comment: Have you looked at defining the original table without any encoding and then change your options of how to load the data into that table from the flat files?  There are options in the COPY INTO statement that might help you out with that.  Mainly, I think if you can get the data into the database without a quoted-text qualifier, then Snowflake will trim automatically for you. https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***None*** of your tables have trimmed data.  It only *appears so* in certain circumstances.

The table `temp.T_ERROR` has *trimmed comparison semantics*, and that means it compares & sorts *as if* it was trimmed.  But assignment is not comparison, and the original value in `temp.T_ERROR` (which is space padded) is copied into the new table `DATA.T_ERROR_1`.  You can check that the spaces are there with eg

```
SELECT '"'||ERROR||'"', LENGTH(ERROR) FROM temp.T_ERROR
```

As [Mike Walton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12178980/mike-walton) says elsewhere, if you have a chance to trim the spaces before the data enters Snowflake, your problems may be solved.  If however you are porting an application that relies heavily on `CHAR` behaviour, you *might* be better off defining `COLLATE` for all the `CHAR` columns.

I've tested on other databases (ie Oracle) and it behaves the same way as Snowflake:  if you copy from `CHAR` to `VARCHAR` you get the padding spaces, too.